# Named scopes for instances

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have following relationship schema:

```
class Participation
  belongs_to :toon
  belongs_to :person

  validates :role, :presence => true
end

class Toon
  has_many :participations
  has_many :people, :through => :participations
end

class Person
  has_many :participations
  has_many :toons, :through => :participations
end
```

I want to get `people` association related to `toon`, but filtered by `role` attribute value. I need something like `toon.people_with_role('producer')`.

```
class Toon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :people, :through => :participations

  def people_with_role(role)
    Participation.where(:toon_id => self, :role => role).map(&:person)   
  end
end
```

It works, but I'm not sure that it is a best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to filter people by role:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :toon
  belongs_to :person

  validates :role, :presence => true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :toons, :through => :participations
end

class Toon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :people, :through => :participations do
    def with_role(role)
      where('participations.role' => role)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you can get the people fitered by role: `toon.people.with_role('producer')`.

Comment: Great, I don't knew that it can be done in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a scope under 'Person' for this, that way you can chain it together with other Person scopes.  something like this should work (may have slight syntax errors).

```
scope :for_toon_with_role, lambda { |toon, role| joins(:participations).where(:participations => {:role => role, :toon_id => toon.id }) }
```

That way you can call it like this:

```
Person.for_toon_with_role(toon, 'role').all
```

Check out more info on rails scopes here:[rails scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)